# C# - How to Upload large size video ( in GB ) to Amazon S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-s3

I need to upload a large size video to Amazon S3 bucket.

I have a large size video and it

> here is my class that i am using

```
 public class CustomAmazon
{
    public string tourName { get; set; }
    public string driveName { get; set; }
    public string tourID { get; set; }
    public string driveID { get; set; }  
    public string key { get; set; }
    public string bucketName { get; set; }
    public string cloudFrontVideoUrl { get; set; }
    public string amazonS3VideoUrl { get; set; }
    public string filePath { get; set; } 
}
```

> and here is the Amazon Code for writing an object

```
 static string WritingAnObject(CustomAmazon customAmazon)
    {
        try
        {
            var videoStream = new FileStream(customAmazon.filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            // put a more complex object with some metadata and http headers.
            string fileName = customAmazon.tourID + "/" + customAmazon.driveID + "/" + Guid.NewGuid() + "__" + Path.GetFileName(customAmazon.filePath);
            PutObjectRequest titledRequest = new PutObjectRequest()
            {
                BucketName = customAmazon.bucketName,
                Key = fileName,
                InputStream = videoStream,
                Timeout = new TimeSpan(4, 30, 30),
                ContentType = "video/mov",
                CannedACL = S3CannedACL.PublicRead
            };

            titledRequest.Metadata.Add("title", fileName);
            titledRequest.Metadata.Add("drive", customAmazon.driveName);
            client.PutObject(titledRequest);
            Thread.Sleep(4000);
            // Retrieve ACL for object
            customAmazon.cloudFrontVideoUrl = customAmazon.cloudFrontVideoUrl + fileName;
            customAmazon.key = fileName;
            customAmazon.amazonS3VideoUrl = ReadConfig.AWSStorageUrl + fileName;

        }
        catch (AmazonS3Exception amazonS3Exception)
        {
            Logger.Write(amazonS3Exception.Message);
            if (amazonS3Exception.ErrorCode != null &&
                (amazonS3Exception.ErrorCode.Equals("InvalidAccessKeyId") ||
                amazonS3Exception.ErrorCode.Equals("InvalidSecurity")))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please check the provided AWS Credentials.");
                Console.WriteLine("If you haven't signed up for Amazon S3, please visit http://aws.amazon.com/s3");
            }
            else
            {
               Logger.Write(string.Format("An error occurred with the message '{0}' when writing an object", amazonS3Exception.Message));
            }
        }
        return customAmazon.amazonS3VideoUrl;
    }
```

I am getting error while uploading large size video, while in small size videos it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I got the answer, I tried it using multicast and it is working fine, here is my solution

> Here is my class

```
 public class CustomAmazon
{
    public string tourName { get; set; }
    public string driveName { get; set; }
    public string tourID { get; set; }
    public string driveID { get; set; }  
    public string key { get; set; }
    public string bucketName { get; set; }
    public string cloudFrontVideoUrl { get; set; }
    public string amazonS3VideoUrl { get; set; }
    public string filePath { get; set; } 
}
```

and here is my solution

I just call below method to upload large video file after connecting credentials

```
 /// <summary>
   /// Method used for DFI (website or API) users to upload a file on Amazon S3 storage
   /// </summary>
   /// <param name="customAmazon"></param>
    /// <returns>CustomAmazon class object </returns>
    public CustomAmazon UploadFiletoAmazonS3Storage(CustomAmazon customAmazon)
    {
            using (client = new AmazonS3Client(ReadConfig.AWSAccessKeyId, ReadConfig.AWSSecretKey, RegionEndpoint.USEast1))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Writing an object");                
                WritingAnLargeObject(customAmazon);                   
            }            
        return customAmazon;
    }

public static string WritingAnLargeObject(CustomAmazon customAmazon)
    {
        // List to store upload part responses.
        List<UploadPartResponse> uploadResponses = new List<UploadPartResponse>();
        string fileName = string.Empty;

// Giving custom filename to original file

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(customAmazon.tourID) && (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(customAmazon.driveID)))
        {
            fileName = customAmazon.tourID + "/" + customAmazon.driveID + "/" + Guid.NewGuid() + "___" + Regex.Replace(Path.GetFileName(customAmazon.filePath), @"\s", "");
        }
        else
        {
            fileName = Guid.NewGuid() + "___" + Regex.Replace(Path.GetFileName(customAmazon.filePath), @"\s", "");
        }

        // 1. Initialize MultipartUploadRequest.
        InitiateMultipartUploadRequest initiateRequest = new InitiateMultipartUploadRequest
        {
            BucketName = customAmazon.bucketName,
            Key = fileName,
            ContentType = "video/mov",
            CannedACL = S3CannedACL.PublicRead
        };



        InitiateMultipartUploadResponse initResponse =
            client.InitiateMultipartUpload(initiateRequest);

        // 2. Upload video in small Parts of 5 MB.
        long contentLength = new FileInfo(customAmazon.filePath).Length;
        long partSize = 5 * (long)Math.Pow(2, 20); // 5 MB

        try
        {
            long filePosition = 0;
            for (int index = 1; filePosition < contentLength; index++)
            {
                UploadPartRequest uploadRequest = new UploadPartRequest
                {
                    BucketName = customAmazon.bucketName,
                    Key = fileName,
                    UploadId = initResponse.UploadId,
                    PartNumber = index,
                    PartSize = partSize,
                    FilePosition = filePosition,
                    FilePath = customAmazon.filePath
                };

                // Upload part and add response to our list.
                uploadResponses.Add(client.UploadPart(uploadRequest));

                filePosition += partSize;
            }

            // Step 3: complete.
            CompleteMultipartUploadRequest completeRequest = new CompleteMultipartUploadRequest
            {
                BucketName = customAmazon.bucketName,
                Key = fileName,
                UploadId = initResponse.UploadId,
                //PartETags = new List<PartETag>(uploadResponses)

            };
            completeRequest.AddPartETags(uploadResponses);
            customAmazon.key = fileName;
            CompleteMultipartUploadResponse completeUploadResponse = client.CompleteMultipartUpload(completeRequest);
            customAmazon.cloudFrontVideoUrl = customAmazon.cloudFrontVideoUrl + fileName;
            customAmazon.amazonS3VideoUrl = ReadConfig.AWSStorageUrl + fileName;
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            Logger.Write(exception.Message);
            Console.WriteLine("Exception occurred: {0}", exception.Message);
            AbortMultipartUploadRequest abortMPURequest = new AbortMultipartUploadRequest
            {
                BucketName = customAmazon.bucketName,
                Key = fileName,
                UploadId = initResponse.UploadId
            };
            client.AbortMultipartUpload(abortMPURequest);
        }
        return fileName;
    }
```

> and Finally I uploaded the video into S3 bucket